# Create classes into test folder

Tags: java, testing, rabbitmq

I have two services, the first it's spring boot rest api service , and the second Event proccessor(java).The main logic is , when client make http request to spring boot service it send message to rabbitmq exchange, the second service listening queue that bind to this exchange name.To test this life cycle , I add class from  spring boot ,that send message to exchange , into test folder of the second service(Event processor). My question is, is it good practise to test things like this one.

Answer (score 0):

It is always up to you, as in your example, you have service sending a message to the queue and a service which is basically processing queue which is an end to end flow so the test you described also end to end and it is based on the rabbitmq also. I will suggest following to tests instead of one e2e:

1. (1st service) Emulate client request and make sure the first service is generating expected message
2. (2nd service) Emulate incoming message and make sure service processing message as it should